# What is the difference between the combination of split inside equation* and align*?

Tags: math-mode

What is the difference between the combination of `split` inside `equation*` and `align*`?

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
A   &= B+C\\
    &= X+Y
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\begin{align*}
A   &= B+C\\
    &= X+Y
\end{align*}
```

Answer (score 3):

As it is here not much. Split can handle just one alignment column, whereas align can handle many more.

This is of course a difference if one remove the stars

Comment: another difference -- `align` can accommodate more than one `split`; `equation` can handle just one.  this becomes more interesting if you want the split things numbered, just one number per `split` as opposed to a number on every line with `align`.